# wxPython Tables to display data on full frame

Tags: grid, wxpython

I can't find anything in the docs. All the code I find is messy and all over the place;
all I want to do, is have a table take up the whole frame, and have 6 columns;

- ID
- Name
- Author
- Type
- Tags
- More Info

The "More Info" column should have a button, which will call a function with the ID column as param. How would I do this? I want to be able to "fill" this table using an array, with each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using a ListCtrl instead? I think that might work better. I especially like the ObjectListView widget, which is a nice object oriented wrapper of the ListCtrl.

Note that neither the grid nor the ListCtrl really support buttons in their cells, although the grid might work better by using a custom renderer. On the other hand, there's a new widget called the UltimateListCtrl that supports putting ANY widget anywhere in it, so that's an option.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed you replied on my other questions as well. Thanks a lot. I hate to be leaching, but what would it look like with ListCtrl? I don't get all the examples on the Wiki pages. Sorry, and thanks again.

Comment: You can run all those widgets from the wxPython Demo. I use it all the time to figure out how various elements work. There's also this article that shows the basic list control in action: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/ and here's one on ObjectListView: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/  I haven't tried the UltimateListCtrl yet, so no articles on that one.